# How can I refer to class variable in a function without referring to its class in Python?

Tags: python

I have a following class:

```
class Foo:
    CONSTANT = 1

    def some_fn(self):
        a = Foo.CONSTANT
        # do something
```

How can I refer to `Foo.CONSTANT` without referring to `Foo`, or refer to `Foo` in a generic way? (I don't want to change all references to it when renaming a class)

Comment: Maybe you should consider a more powerful IDE instead? Eclipse + PyDev has some pretty powerful refactoring tools — in a situation like this, you can just Refactor > Rename "Foo" to "Bar" and it'll take care of all of that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within a method of class `Foo` or any subclass thereof, `self.CONSTANT` will refer to the value defined for that class attribute in class `Foo` (unless it's overridden in a subclass or in the instance itself -- if you **assign** `self.CONSTANT=23`, it's the **instance** attribute that's created with that value, and it overrides the **class** attribute in future references).

Comment: For some reason I did not think of the obvious first.

Comment: Unless he refers to it using `self.__class__.CONSTANT`. That way, the reassignment is still bound to the class variable, and not overridden (if this is indeed the desired behavior). ;-)

Comment: @Santa, if the instance is of a derived class from `Foo`, `self.__class__.CONSTANT = 23` will create or rebind that attribute on the _derived_ class, **not** rebind `Foo`'s -- so things are a bit more delicate than you describe them.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why self.CONSTANT doesn't suit your needs?

```
class Foo:
    CONSTANT = 1

    def some_fn(self):
        a = self.CONSTANT
        # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `self.CONSTANT` will work, but if you ever assign to `self.CONSTANT`, that will "override" the value defined on the class.

You can use `self.__class__.CONSTANT` to always refer to the value defined on the class. You can even assign to that.

Comment: It's CONSTANT, he shouldn't be assigning to it.

Comment: The only constant is change. =)